# Update table - relation does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying this query, however is not working:
The idea is copy data from one table to another.

```
UPDATE  A
SET     A.name_en = B.name
FROM    country_name as A
        INNER JOIN country as B
            ON A.id = B.id
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in query: ERROR: relation "a" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE A
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the extra join here at all. You're doing an `inner join` so you can just do it with `from` and `where` clause instead:

```
UPDATE  country_name
SET     name_en = B.name
FROM    country AS B
WHERE   counry_name.id = B.id;
```

The only time you need to do the `UPDATE sometable ... FROM sometable a ... WHERE sometable.id = a.id` trick is when you need to do an outer join against the table being updated.

It's unfortunate that PostgreSQL's `UPDATE ... FROM ...` feature doesn't let you use explicit join syntax.

Comment: @Brandon Sure; all I'm saying is that you don't need the *self-join*, where you reference `country_name` again from the `FROM` clause, if you only need an inner join.

Comment: @CraigRinger The first example work but not the second. http://sharetext.org/uMTT

Comment: @user2990084 Sorry, silly error on my part, forgot to remove all reference to the alias. Amended. The reason the second didn't work is that you're not allowed to use a table name on the left hand side of a SET assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to write the real name of the table because the action will be taken outside of the query itself. Therefor, the association will be over.

```
UPDATE  country_name
SET     A.name_en = B.name
FROM    country_name as A
        INNER JOIN country as B
            ON A.id = B.id
WHERE   A.id = B.id;
```

took the where from the other person's answer just to make sure you don't make a mistake in your DB.

Comment: Yes, but **DO NOT RUN THIS** as written, it's missing a `WHERE` clause to limit the update to entries in `country_name` that match the join against the aliased version of `country_name A`.

Comment: I'm getting column A of relation contry_name does not exist :(